# Routing and templates on AngularJS in Rails. How to route to templates?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I'd like to ask help on rendering templates for AngularJS and Rails. What's the correct way to render that template? Looking at several answers here and some tutorials, I'm kinda stuck.

Thing is, I can render the {{header}} in my application.html.erb, but not the {{templateContent}} or anything from my intended template. What am I missing? And if possible, can anyone create another angular controller routing to another template?

My template is in:

```
app
-assets
|-templates
|--homepage.html.erb
```

Thanks in advance!

Here are my files:

// application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WebApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body ng-app="web_app" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">

    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">AngularUI Router</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="header">{{header}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
        <div ui-view></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

// app.js

```
var appModule = angular.module('web_app', ['ui.router', 'templates']);

appModule.controller('HomeCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        function($scope){
            $scope.header = 'Hello world!';
            $scope.templateContent = 'This is a content!';

        }
    ]);

appModule.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: 'homepage.html'
        });

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    }]);
```

// application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require angular
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require app.js
//= require_tree ../templates
```

// Added this in my Gemfile

```
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
```

// homepage.html.erb

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>The Homey Page</h1>
    <p>This page demonstrates <span class="text-danger">nested</span> views.</p>    
</div>
```

// routes.rb

```
  root to: 'application#angular'
```

Comment: I think your issue is the `templateUrl`. You should use `templateUrl: 'homepage.html'` ([docs](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates#4-use-your-templates)) and not `templateUrl: 'app/assets/templates/homepage.html'` ([your code](https://github.com/frozenrevolver/angularrailstests/blob/master/web_app/app/assets/javascripts/app.js#L20))

Comment: Hi @JobaDiniz . Oh, that was from my repo. I tried using that absolute path after the code above didn't work.  `$stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: 'homepage.html'
        });` I was looking at the documentation but couldn't see what I really missed.

Comment: You need to figure it out either is a server side error (ruby) or client error (javascript). Does `localhost:3000/#/home` show anything? If it shows the main template but not show the homepage.html, it could be that indeed ui-router is not finding the homepage.html to render. Have tried to debug this? Setup [events](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#events) callbacks in order to see if there is any error.

Comment: Yes, it shows what I put in application.html.erb even its angular controller. Just not finding homepage.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: It seems this was caused by the incompatibility of Sprockets 3.1.0 with angular-rails-templates.

This solution got my app working:
[angular-rails-templates: templates are not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749099/angular-rails-templates-templates-are-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

For your `home` state you have configured the controller `MainCtrl`:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/homepage',
      templateUrl: '/homepage.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });
```

And you expect the `{{templateContent}}` to be rendered in the configured template `homepage.html`. It's the problem with scope, you should configure the controller of state to be `HomeCtrl` where proper variable is set, or add `$scope.templateContent` in your `MainCtrl`, so it is visible in your template.

Hope that helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Hi. Looks like I missed that one out but I changed it now to `controller: 'HomeCtrl'` and still didn't work. I added another line without variables like `<h1>{{templateContent}}</h1>
<h1> THIS IS A CONTENT </h1>` in my `homepage.html.erb`. that should work without defining variables right? I think my problem now lies on why I could not find `homepage.html.erb` to be rendered in `ng-view`.

Comment: Ok @bitfrost41, first of all - try adding "#home" to your URL in web browser. I guess, this is the problem with improper redirection. If this is what fixes your problem, you should update `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');` to be `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/homepage');` - it should point to configured "url", not "state". Hope this helps! Let me know, so we can dig that in further!

Comment: Hi Pawel. Thanks so much for giving time to help! I did what you said. on $urlRouterProvider and even adding invoking http://localhost:3000/#/homepage but still can't see something on my ui-view. I added my routes.rb if that could help.

Comment: \@PawelDawczak - i updated my files above btw. Looking at several tutorials for ui-router, i can't really find what i'm missing out.

Comment: i uploaded my project in a git repository if it helps. https://github.com/frozenrevolver/angularrailstests