# angular-rails-templates: templates are not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute, angularjs-templates

I have a rails application, using angularjs for the client side development. I try to load a template located in `app/assets/javascripts/templates/':

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/index.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

but I always get a error: "Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /index.html".

I tried to move the "templates" folder out of the javascripts - app/assets/templates and to add it to my assets pipeline load by adding the following line to config/application.rb: `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app","assets","templates")`

I keep getting the same error message until I use the full path to the template: `templateUrl: '/assets/index.html',`.

1. Why the first method is not enough? the angular-rails-templates gem shouldn't look for templates in app/assets/javascripts/templates?
2. Why should I use the full path to an assets inside my javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My problem has been a `sprockets` incompatibility. Version 2.1.3 works though so I put this in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3'
```

And I ran `bundle update sprockets` and it's all peachy.

Comment: Have you got `//= require_tree ./templates` in your `application.js`?

Comment: yes, it shows "GET http://localhost:3000/index.html 404 (Not Found)" so I guess it doesn't look in the templates folder.

Comment: That was exactly my problem until I did the above. Have you restarted your server?

Comment: It's worth noting that as I struggled with this problem lots of people recommended not using the rails asset pipeline and just putting templates into `/public/templates` or something like that.

Comment: do you agree with this approach of giving up the assets?

Comment: The best argument seems to be that the client doesn't need all the templates to begin with and so initial load is faster even if more http requests are made along the way. That's good logic to me but I can't figure out why everyone seems to be recommending the `angular-rails-templates` gem if that's the case.

Answer (score 4):

Practice has shown that you should keep Angular templates in `./public` folder. For example make a folder called templates in the `public` folder. Now you can just call them like this: `templateUrl: 'templates/index.html'`

This makes sense as the `app/assets/` is indeed only used for javascript and css files. Also you have the html files in `app/views`, but these are compiled by server because they use `.erb` extension. What you want is to have regular `html` files ready to be used any time. So you put them to public folder.

Comment: I see that this works but I don't understand why the `angular-rails-templates` gem exists if this is the case.

Comment: Because some people feel the need to break the pattern and keep the html partials in the javascript folder. This should not be a huge concern with a smaller application. When things get bigger, it would be better to keep them in public folder.

Comment: Another reason is that some people want to use html preprocessors like `haml` or `slim` for the views. You can't use preprocessors if you will put the views in `/public`.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I hope this will worked.

```
 myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
     templateUrl: '/index.html',
     controller: 'MainController'
    }).
    otherwise({
     redirectTo: '/'
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding "gem 'sprockets'" into the Gemfile